# Can write to stdout using latin-1 encoding but not to a file (Python 2.6)

Tags: python, utf-8, latin1

I have data which is unicode and wish to write it to a file. I am using python 2.6. I am able to print the encoded values but am not able to write it to a file. The default encoding for the environment is UTF-8. Tried using codecs as well, but no luck there too.  Here is a sample code snippet that I am using.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import codecs
import csv

sh = [u'T\xe9l\xe9vista S.A.', u'T\xe9l\xe9vista S.A.', 'Python']
print sys.stdout.encoding
f = codecs.open('listwrite.txt', 'w', encoding='latin-1')
for item in sh:
  f.write(item)
f.close()

for i in sh:
  print i.encode('latin-1')
```

#

Output:

```
UTF-8
Télévista S.A.
Télévista S.A.
Python

Contents of listwrite.txt
TÃ©lÃ©vista S.A.TÃ©lÃ©vista S.A.Python
```

#

As seen above the file is being written in UTF-8 encoding and not Latin-1. How do I change it and override the default encoding for the file.

**Edit: 2**

Also, writing using a csv writer gives UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import codecs
import csv

sh = [u'T\xe9l\xe9vista S.A.', u'T\xe9l\xe9vista S.A.', 'Python']
print sys.stdout.encoding
c = csv.writer(codecs.open('listwrite.txt', 'w', encoding='latin-1'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
c.writerow(sh)
f.close()

for i in sh:
  print i.encode('latin-1')
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Python 2.6. For me, `listwrite.txt` contains Latin-1 encoded data when I run your example code. How are you verifying the contents?

Comment: I know one way is to change the default encoding in site.py. I don't want to use that road. Is any other workaround possible to just write to the file using latin-1 on the fly? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Just doing a cat or seeing it in vi!

Comment: Sorry, doing a cat on the file has latin-1 but opening using vi has UTF-8. I am confused now.

Comment: Try looking at it outside of a terminal (any text editor, etc.) - depending on your setup, you will get a different result when viewing output in the terminal as opposed to a non-terminal text editor, etc.

Comment: No, the default encoding is site.py only applies to automatic conversions, but when using `codecs.open` you specify an explicit encoding. Besides, my default is still ASCII (and it should stay that way).

Comment: @RocketDonkey is correct. When I open it in some other editor, I can see latin encoding. I am wondering why vi shows UTF-8. Anyways I think  this should work for me. I had read in a few posts that the default should be ASCII, but mine is UTF-8. Not sure how or who changed it.

Comment: Is your output reasonable? If `sys.stdout.encoding` is `UTF-8`, how can you get the print result of `latin-1` encoded characters properly?

Comment: @Reorx: Sorry, did not get you. Yes, sys.stdout.encoding is UTF-8. But am able to print latin-1 using encoding on standard output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Can you guys please look at Edit 2 and let me know why it fails?

Comment: @user1827064: When using the `csv` module, you need to encode to bytes yourself.

Comment: closed? are all python 2.x questions being closed now? or is latin1 a to small geographical region? what am I missing, please help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're attacking the problem from a wrong angle. Try encoding each row before writing instead:

```
import csv
sh = [u'T\xe9l\xe9vista S.A.', u'T\xe9l\xe9vista S.A.', 'Python']

f = open('listwrite.txt', 'wb') # binary mode
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow([item.encode('latin-1') for item in sh])
f.close()
```

Now you have a proper latin1-encoded file:

```
$ cat listwrite.txt | iconv -f latin1
Télévista S.A.,Télévista S.A.,Python
$ file listwrite.txt 
listwrite.txt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
```